# A document opens every time I start Word

Tags: microsoft-word

The same document opens every time I open word. How do I correct this? Microsoft Word 2007.
Windows Vista.

Comment: I edited your subject line--this will be more meaningful when someone sees it in a list. "Microsoft Word question" contains very little information. You should edit your own question to add more information, like the version of Word and more details.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you either changed your default document, or are clicking on a .doc/.docx shortcut that is launching Word.

First, if it is the second one, make sure you are clicking on a standard Microsoft Word shortcut and not a document.

If you are, and it is simply opening a new document with text already there, you simply need to reset your `normal.dot` (Word 2003 and below), or your `normal.dotx` (Word 2007 and above).

This file is located in `%appdata%\microsoft\templates`(Copy and paste that to the run box or explorer address bar, it should go to the correct folder.)

Once you have the file, simply open it, delete everything inside it / set the font however you like it and then choose save, make sure you select template in the extension type, and replace the normal.dot/x file. The next time you start, it should always open with this document.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Wil. What do I do after I open the file?

Comment: I guess I need to know how to reset it?

Comment: @Tori, so sorry, left out the most important bit! Updated now, hope that helps!